# How to test asynchronous queries with rhino mocks

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, iqueryable

Following is my function

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<Books>> GetAsync(Guid customerId) {
        var BookList= await _bookStore.FindBy(AnExpression(customerId)).ToListAsync();
        return vehicleList;
    }
```

I tried to mock the _bookStore.FindBy() Method which returns IQueryable

```
  var Books= new List<Books>(2){
                new Books(),
                new Books()
            }.AsQueryable();

 mock.Expect(viewStore => viewStore.FindBy(Arg<Expression<Func<Books, bool>>>.Is.Anything)).Return(Books);
```

`viewStore` is an interface:

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable where T : class
{
    IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
}
```

I am getting following error

**System.InvalidOperationException: The source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncEnumerable. Only sources that implement IDbAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations**

I tried implementing AsyncQueryProvider like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429#async

But the implementation is shown with Moq not with Rhino mock.

Comment: please add the code of `_vehicleViewStore`.

Comment: @OldFox. Its actually bookStore and its repository object. Basically dbcontext. EntityFramework

Comment: I know it... I asked for the implementation because I want to debug my answer before I....

Comment: return Context.Set<T>().Where(predicate);

Comment: It's the body of the method :\ I asked for the class which you mocked (`_vehicleViewStore`)

Comment: Its a repository.   public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable where T : class{ IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89143/discussion-between-markand-bhatt-and-old-fox).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `TestDbAsyncEnumerable` which is implemented in the link you've provided.

Replace:

```
var Books= new List<Books>(2){
            new Books(),
            new Books()
        }.AsQueryable();

mock.Expect(viewStore => viewStore.FindBy(Arg<Expression<Func<Books, bool>>>.Is.Anything))
    .Return(Books);
```

with:

```
var Books = new List<Books>(2){
            new Books(),
            new Books()
        }.AsQueryable();

var asycEnumarable = new TestDbAsyncEnumerable<Books>(Books);

var viewStore = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IRepository<Books>>();

viewStore.Stub(x => x.FindBy(Arg<Expression<Func<Books, bool>>>.Is.Anything))
         .Return(asycEnumarable);
```